# How to press enter when searching in the drop down list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdownlist and you can type the text for searching keyword. After that you need to select the searching result or press to enter. 
My code is written as follows:

```
Utils.driver.findElement(ProductObject.ddlDummyUnit).click();
Utils.driver.findElement(ProductObject.txtUnit).sendKeys(CommonExcel.readCellData(indexR, 3, ExcelWSheet));
```

But i don't known how to press enter when searching in  the drop down list.

Please help me!

Comment: `WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);` where `WebElement` is the dropdown element that you have already captured hopefully.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'll try :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Note for anyone who had similar problems :)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

Utils.driver.findElement(ProductObject.ddlDummyUnit).click();
WebElement Unit = Utils.driver.findElement(ProductObject.txtUnit);
Unit.sendKeys(CommonExcel.readCellData(indexR, 3, ExcelWSheet));
Unit.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with selenium action builder for generating a sequence of actions though it not available for all browsers.

Check out this link,
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Advanced-User-Interactions